# All three of my professors asked me to write the first draft of my Letter of Recommendation.

Tags: graduate-admissions, professorship, recommendation-letter

I just finished writing for one of them but I still have two more to write. Though my interactions with all three of them have been on different occasions, there are still limited things I can write about myself without overdoing things.
I am just not sure how should I approach writing the rest two? Should I just repeat everything I wrote in the first one?
I am quite sure they will add/remove a couple of lines only. So if I just copy the contents, they will look all the same. If I don't then I fear I will miss important points about myself.

Comment: Yes, this is very common. I think this is a nasty request to ask students to write their own letters. But you have to do it as best as you can.

Comment: Would you suggest I go ahead and write the same things in all the three letters?

Comment: Do you think a faculty member isn't going to get suspicious reading the same text in three different letters?

Comment: That is true. But then how should I do it? Should I skip certain points in one, include them in the other? Most of my research interactions has been with only one of them. Should I write the other two only detailing academic performance?